# encoding url in javascript not encoding &

Tags: javascript, url-encoding

I am encoding the following string in javascript

```
encodeURI = "?qry=M & L";
```

This give me an output

```
qry=m%20&%20l
```

So the "&" from `M & L` is not getting encoded. What should i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does not encode characters that have special meaning (reserved
>   characters) for a URI. The following example shows all the parts that
>   a URI "scheme" can possibly contain.

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI#Description)

[`encodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) will not encode following special charcaters

```
A-Z a-z 0-9 ; , / ? : @ & = + $ - _ . ! ~ * ' ( ) #
```

```js
let uri = "?qry=M & L"

console.log(encodeURI(uri))
```

So you can use [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) ,this will encode all the characters except these

```
A-Z a-z 0-9 - _ . ! ~ * ' ( )
```

```js
let uri = "?qry=M & L"

console.log(encodeURIComponent(uri))
```

Answer (score 1):

use encoreURIComponent instead to encode `&` as `%26` as shown below. 
But it also encodes other special chars like `?` and `=`

```js
let uri = "?qry=M & L"

console.log(encodeURIComponent(uri))
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`encodeURI()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) is not going to encode `&` as it will only encode certain set of special characters. to encode `&` you need to use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

`encodeURI` encodes everything except:

```
A-Z a-z 0-9 ; , / ? : @ & = + $ - _ . ! ~ * ' ( ) #
```

`encodeURIComponent` encodes everything except:

```
A-Z a-z 0-9 - _ . ! ~ * ' ( )
```

```js
console.log(encodeURIComponent("?qry=M & L"));
```

Note the difference between the two methods when used to encode URLs.

```js
const URL = "https://www.example.com/resource?query=10&id=20&name=hello%"

console.log(encodeURI(URL));
console.log(encodeURIComponent(URL));
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI#Description):

> Note that encodeURI by itself cannot form proper HTTP GET and POST
>   requests, such as for XMLHTTPRequests, because "&", "+", and "=" are
>   not encoded, which are treated as special characters in GET and POST
>   requests. encodeURIComponent, however, does encode these characters

Answer (score 0):

You should be using encodeURIComponent() instead of encodeURI()

> **Note**: Usually encodeURIComponent() is used to encode a string (query string), that would be put to the URL. If you are using an existing URL to be encoded, then you may use encodeURI()

```
const uri = "?qry=M & L";

console.log(encodeURIComponent(uri));
```

**Reference**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Answer (score 0):

Reference here: [url encode](https://url-encode.com/code/javascript)
You have three options:

```
escape(str) will not encode: * @ - _ + . /
encodeURI(uri) will not encode: ~!@#$&*()=:/,;?+'
encodeURIComponent(uri) will not encode: ~!*()'
```

Answer (score -1):

From [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp)

The encodeURI() function is used to encode a URI.

This function encodes special characters, except: , / ? : @ & = + $ # (Use `encodeURIComponent()` to encode these characters).

And, also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/encode-url-in-javascript)

So, you'll probably have to do something like

```
var inputWithSplChars = "M & L";
encodeURI  = "?qry=" + encodeURIComponent(inputWithSplChars);
```

Hope this helps! Cheers!