# reading a url in PHP that has been encoded in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, url-encoding

In Javascript i encode parts of the request parameter like this

```
window.location.href = "search.php?qry=" + encodeURIComponent("m & l");
```

In my Search.php i reach this  like this

```
$url = urldecode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
echo ."Full URL: " .$url ."<br>";
$parts = parse_url($url);
parse_str($parts['query'], $query);
$qry = "Just Query: " .trim($query['qry']);
echo $qry ."<br>";
```

This prints out:

```
Full Url: /Search.php?qry=m & l
Just Query: m
```

Looks like the stuff after the `&` is being dropped in the 'm & l`

What changes do i need to make in PHP or Javascript?

Comment: Can you give concrete example of your desired result?

Comment: the `Just Query:` echo statement should have printed `Just Query: m & l`

Comment: You just asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54602850/encoding-url-in-javascript-not-encoding), shouldn't this have been an edit?

Comment: possibly, but i thought that one was about encoding and this one is about decoding. What help can i get with this please?

Comment: @Jack Bashford - I actually chose to answer because it seemed like a separate, but related question to me. I could also see why decoding the result separately and then passing that to `parse_url` might not behave the way the asker was expecting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change:

```
$url = urldecode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

to

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

You're basically double-decoding as `parse_url` will decode it as well.

Worth noting that PHP has already done this for you so there's not really a reason to parse your own URL. `$_GET['qry']` will contain `'m & l'`

If you're doing this for several query variables, you'll need to run `encodeURIComponent` separately for each.

Example:

```
window.location.href = "search.php?qry=" + encodeURIComponent("m & l") + "&subcat="+encodeURIComponent("hello & there");
```

You're explicitly telling it to encode the & after all.

Comment: i tried the using the PHP way like you recommended. Works if i only have one paramenter in the url. But when i have two this is what happens.
`$qry = trim($_GET['qry']);`
`echo $qry ;`

this prints out. `M & L&subcat=` so the second query param is being clubbed in

Comment: I added an edit for situations where you want to send several query variables. Since you'd be encoding the separator, you'll need to encode them separately.